# Unrecognizable situation

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
            mysql_select_db('db');
    $$checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `Username` FROM `users` WHERE `EmailAddress` = '".$email."'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
 {
    echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again.')
    </SCRIPT>";
 }
 else
 {
echo 'Username Available';
}
```

In actual, the username is not available but still it echoes 'Username Available'. I have also tried this but still the same:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `EmailAddress` = '".$email."'");
```

I dont know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated!

Comment: A side-note: Avoid using `mysql`, it is deprecated and should be replaced in new code with either `PDO` or `MySQLi`. Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the double dollar signs:

```
   $$checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `Username` FROM `users` WHERE `EmailAddress` = '".$email."'");
```

should be

```
   $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT `Username` FROM `users` WHERE `EmailAddress` = '".$email."'");
```

Comment: Ohh my bad, It is $checkusername only.

Comment: In addition, please avoid the use of mysql_* as it is deprecated.